# How do i check if items already exist in the List?

Tags: c#, .net

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++)
{
    if (!newText.Contains(t[i]))
    {
        if (firsttime > 1)
        {                           
                newText.Insert(0, string.Empty);
                newText.Insert(0, ExtractLinks.FilteredLinks[i]);
                newText.Insert(0, dateTimeList[i]);
                newText.Insert(0, t[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            newText.Add(t[i]);
            newText.Add(dateTimeList[i]);
            newText.Add(ExtractLinks.FilteredLinks[i]);
            newText.Add(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this for loop many times over again through timer tick event.
In the first time the variable t (`List<string>`) contain 43 items.
And the `List<string> newText` contains 172 items.

I want to check if any item of `t` already exist in `newText` not add it again to `newText`.

The problem I think is that I'm looping over `t.Count` and I should somehow also loop over `newText`?
How can i fix it so the condition will work fine ?

Comment: Have you tried HashSet instead of List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a version of the framework that allows for you to use `System.Linq` you can use the `Any()` extension:

```
newText.Any(r => t.Contains(r));
```

If there is even one member of `newText` that is also found in `t` the extension will return true.

Edit: as an afterthought you can probably do this even more elegantly with `.Except()` extension but I would recommend you get this working in a simple way before you attempt any real optimization.

Edit 2:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new List<string>();        // starts with 43 items
        var newText = new List<string>();  // starts with 172 items

        t.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 43).Cast<string>());
        newText.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 172).Cast<string>());

        // add only members t that do not exist in set newText (44..172 added)
        newText.AddRange(t.Except(newText));
    }
```

Comment: If both `newText` and `t` are List, then the complexity is `O(N*N)`. I would not use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the item and remove all duplicated entries with

```
yourList.Distinct().ToList();
```